# NoMethodError (undefined method `primary_key' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Public Activity gem to create a activity stream on my app. For that I have this setup.

I have set up a friendship model for my app,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And the model looks like this,

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

And this is my user model,

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

And I have tracked my movie model with the Public Activity gem,

```
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked owner: -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
tracked recipient:  -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user.friends }
tracked :params => {
  :title => :get_title,
  :poster => :get_poster
}

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

When I add a new movie, and thus create a new activity, I get this error in my rails console,

> NoMethodError (undefined method `primary_key' for User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:Class):
>     app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:19:in`create'

And that refers to this create def in my movies_controller,

```
def create
   @movie = Movie.find_or_create_by movie_params
   current_user.movies << @movie
   redirect_to :root
end
```

What's going wrong here?

*** as requested the movie parameters ***

```
private
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(
    :title,
    :image,
    :imdb_rating,
    :release_date,
    :movie_id,
    :backdrop
  )
end
```

Comment: Do your User model `has_and_belongs_to_many :movies`?

Comment: Also, please post your `movie_params` method in movies_controller, it may be the problem.

Comment: @HoangPhan yes my user model has `has_and_belongs_to_many :movies`. I've updated the question with the movie controller.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma can you check whether `@movie` object was successfully created..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it! Your problem is here:

```
tracked recipient:  -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user.friends }
```

I think `tracked` method asks for a model record(or nil), but your `controller.current_user.friends` return an **association**, so it does not have `primary_key`. You could change it to `controller.current_user.friends.try(:first)` to verify.

Comment: There seems to be something going on now yea. `current_user.friends.try(:first) }` results in, `"recipient_id":1,"recipient_type":"User"`. Also the `recipient_id` changes when I change the first friend :). 

So I guess problem here is, how do we set up multiple recipients?

Comment: Yeah, you ask exactly what I thought :). My advice: don't use default tracking for this case, it designed only for 1 owner and 1 recipient for each record. You could set it up easily in your `create` method like this: `current_user.friends.each { |friend| @movie.create_activity(key: 'movie.create', owner: current_user, recipient: friend) }`

Comment: This goes a little bit over my head. Do you mean the movie create method? Hm okay using that method it creates a record for each friend.

Comment: Well I guess doing `@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)` in my activity record could work. Going to test it.